# Android ListView Color

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm working on a Android application. In my application I'm using a listview. This is the code that I'm using

```
ListView listSearchResults = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewSearchResults);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, searchResults);
listSearchResults.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

"searchresults" is a string array. When I run my application list view text appearing in white. I didn't change anything, I used the same code in another view it's getting displayed in black. Why is it automatically changing its color? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Use the `Activity` `Context`.

Comment: Maybe one of the parent views has a specific style on them to alter the color or has a whole other theme.

Comment: are you sure you what to use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read through [this tutorial on `Context`](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/)

For layout inflation with the Application Context, it says:

> This is legal, but inflation will be done with the default theme for the system on which you are running, not what’s defined in your application.

I suspect that this is causing it to look slightly different.  Instead, try using the Activity context for the adapter.

Comment: Problem I faced is i was using this code block in a callback function, so I couldn't use "this" keyword for the context that is why I used getApplicationContext(). But now I changed it to getBaseContext() now its working fine. Thanks for your answer. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Check the `theme` from the `Mainfest` xml file of both parents and you will find out that they are different. Example:

```
<... android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black">
```

Another way to solve the problem is to force the color from the XML of of your sample `simple_spinner_item` as following:

```
 android:textColor="#ffffff"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting Black Screen while Scrolling in ListView than Add an attribute on the ListView Tag:

> android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" or android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

For more details check [this blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html)